# Trying to authenticate email and password with localhost database

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, authentication, cordova

Hi I have been trying to create a authentication login for my phonegap mobile application however when testing on my web browser, when I enter the values for email and password (exact same as those stored on localhost database) in the login form I always receive an alert saying alert 'You have entered the wrong Email and Password'.

I have a strong feeling that it has something to do with my login.js file

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){

    if(validateEmail() && validateUserPassword())
    {
    $.post('libs/auth.php',$('form').serialize(),function(response){
    if(response == 'true')
    {
    alert('You Have logged in successfully');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $.mobile.changePage('index.php', { transition: "slide"});
        },2000);
    }
    else
    {
    alert('You have entered the wrong Email and Password');
    }
    });
    }

    validateEmail();
    function validateEmail(){
    if($('#email').val().length == 0)
    {
    alert('Email is empty');
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
    return true;
    }


    }
    validateUserPassword();
    function validateUserPassword(){
    if($('#password').val().length == 0)
    {
    alert('Password is empty');
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
    return true;
    }

    }



    })
})
```

Just in case this isn't the problem I will include the various other relevant pieces of code:

Login Button from login.php

```
<div id="loginButtonDiv" data-role="field-contain">
    <button name="login" type="submit" data-inline="true">Log-In</button>
    </div> <!-- End login button div -->
```

Database Class (class.database.php)

```
<?php

    class ManageDatabase{

    protected $db_conn;
    protected $db_host = 'localhost';
    protected $db_name = 'users';
    protected $db_user = 'root';
    protected $db_pass = '';

    function connect(){
        try{
            $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name",$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
            return $this->db_conn;


        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
                return $e->getMessage();

        }

        }
    }


?>
```

class.manageUsers.php

```
<?php

    include_once( 'class.database.php' );


    class ManageUsers{
        protected $link;    
        function __construct(){

        $db_conn = new ManageDatabase;
        $this->link = $db_conn->connect();
        return $this->link;

}
function loginUsers($email,$password)
        {
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password' LIMIT 1");
        $rowCount = $query->rowCount();
        return $rowCount;

        }
}

?>
```

auth.php file

```
<?php
    if($_POST)
    {

    include_once( '../core/class.manageUsers.php' );

    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    if(empty($email) && empty($password))
    {
        echo 'All fields are required';
        }
        else{
            $password = md5($password);
            $init = new ManageUsers;
            $login = $init->loginUsers($email,$password);

            if($login == 1)
            {
            echo 'true';

            }
            else{
            echo 'invalid credentials';
            }
}
}


?>
```

Any help with solving this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability... And other than your initial connection, your DB code is simply assuming success at all stages. This is a bad assumption.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I would go about improving this?